# How to avoid shock (particularly Oblique shock) inside Cd nozzle?

Tags: supersonic, engine-design, propulsion, shock-waves

Using the Area ratio (A/A*) and for the desired exit Mach number I have designed a cd nozzle. The Inlet total pressure (Po) and the total temperature (To) is calculated using Isentropic relations for the optimum condition.

FLUENT CONDITIONS:

Solver type: Density-based, Absolute, 2d, Axisymmetric

Model: Energy On, Inviscid

Material: Air (Ideal gas)

Boundary condition:
Inlet- Pressure inlet- 792812.3356 Pa; Supersonic/Initial Gauge pressure: 790000 Pa; Total Temperature: 518.4 K

Outlet- Pressure outlet- 101325 Pa; Backflow total temperature: 288 K

Operating condition- 0 Pa

For this condition, I should get an ideal flow throughout the nozzle, but there's an oblique shock inside the cd nozzle. Is this a design flaw or any error in the ANSYS fluent conditions?

How to avoid Oblique shock inside CD nozzle?

[image: Geometry]

[image: Mach contour]

[image: Pressure contour]